# Backbone error while posting json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backbone.js

I somehow made basic to-do list, but without ability to save tasks on a server. Now started implementing server side, but having a hard time grasping the whole idea of how is that all supposed to communicate with each other. Here's what I tried to do: in a TodoView (which is rendering the list) I made a model with input value and via save() method tried to post in on a server. As i said I lack grasping a general idea, how is that json supposed to be saved on a server (will it be saved in a tasks.json file which I passed in Collection?). Any help, tips and directions would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my Backbone code

```
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    default: {
        task: '',
        completed: false
    }
});

var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model,
    url: '/tasks.json'
});

var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    render: function () {
        this.$el.data('cid', this.model.cid);
        this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON().task);
        return this;
    }
});

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#todo',

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new Collection();
        this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
        // this.collection.fetch();
    },

    events: {
        'click .add': 'add',
        'dblclick li': 'destroy',
        'keydown': 'keyEvent'
    },

    add: function () {
        // this.collection.add(new Model({ //adding input as an model to collection
        //  task: this.$('#todo').val(),
        //  completed: false
        // })); 
        var taskData = {
            task: this.$('#todo').val(),
            completed: false
        };
        var newlyCreatedModel = new Model({
            task: this.$('#todo').val(),
            completed: false
        });
        newlyCreatedModel.save({
            // url: '/tasks.json',
            data: JSON.stringify(taskData),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });

        this.$('#todo').val(''); //clearing input field
        this.$('#todo').focus(); //focusing input after adding task
    },

    keyEvent: function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            this.add();
        }
    },

    destroy: function (e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(e.target).data('cid');
        var model = this.collection.get(id);
        model.destroy();
        e.target.remove();
    },

    render: function (newModel) {
        var self = this,
            todoView;

            todoView = new ItemView({
                model: newModel
            });

            self.$('.list').append(todoView.render().el); 

        return this;
    }

});

var trigger = new TodoView();
```

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="todo">
        <label for="todo">Write your task</label>
        <input type="text" id='todo'><button class='add'>add</button>
        <ul class='list'>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally here's my server written on node.js with help of express.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var server = express();

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/test'));

server.post('/somepath', function (req, res) {
    var bodyStr = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        bodyStr += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', function (chunk) {
        // res.send(bodyStr);
        console.log(bodyStr);
    }); 
});

var server = server.listen(8888);
```

Comment: I think a complete answer on how to build a backend and have your app talk to it would be way too broad for this format, so I'll just use a comment to suggest having a look at a tutorial that deals with talking to a REST backend. All of https://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/ is a good read and I would suggest looking over at least the whole two first exercises. You could jump straight to the backend part of exercise two, but you might loose out on some context if you do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this book, seems like a solid work! Hope it'll clear things up for me.

Comment: I would recommend learning how to do AJAX  with plain old JavaScript before learning how to do it with Backbone, largely because Backbone does the AJAX bit behind-the-scenes for you, and expects you to already know what is going on there.